# Vhdl counter for heart beat sensor

Tags: vhdl

I want to make a counter for my heart beat sensor in vhdl. I have a sensor that lights up at every heart beat I want to count how many times led lighted but the code is missing some beats.

My code

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity pulse is port(
    heartin : in std_logic;
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    F : out std_logic_vector ( 6 downto 0)
);
end pulse;

architecture Behavioral of pulse is

    component clkdivider is Port (
        clkin: in std_logic;
        clkout:out std_logic
    );
    end component;
    signal x : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0):= "0000";
    signal y : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
    signal wire: std_logic;

begin
    L2:clkdivider port map (clkin=>clk, clkout=>wire);

    process(wire) 
    begin
        if rising_edge (wire) then
            if reset = '1' then
                x <= "0000";
            elsif heartin = '1' then
                x <= (x + "0001");
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(x,y)
    begin
        case x is
            when "0000"=> y<="1000000";  -- '0'
            when "0001"=> y<="1111001";  -- '1'
            when "0010"=> y<="0100100";  -- '2'
            when "0011"=> y<="0110000";  -- '3'
            when "0100"=> y<="0011001";  -- '4' 
            when "0101"=> y<="0010010";  -- '5'
            when "0110"=> y<="0000010";  -- '6'
            when "0111"=> y<="1111000";  -- '7'
            when "1000"=> y<="0000000";  -- '8'
            when "1001"=> y<="0010000";  -- '9'
            when "1010"=> y<="0001000";  -- 'A'
            when "1011"=> y<="0000011";  -- 'b'
            when "1100"=> y<="1000110";  -- 'C'
            when "1101"=> y<="0100001";  -- 'd'
            when "1110"=> y<="0000110";  -- 'E'
            when others=> y<="0001110";  -- 'F'     

        end case;   
    end process;

    F <= y;

end Behavioral;
```

Clkdivider code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity clkdivider is Port (
    clkin: in std_logic;
    clkout:out std_logic
);
end clkdivider;

architecture Behavioral of clkdivider is
    signal int_clock:std_logic;
begin
    clkout<=int_clock;
    process(clkin)
        variable var:integer range 0 to 2200000 :=0;
    begin
        if (clkin'event and clkin = '1') then
            if var = 2200000 then
                int_clock <= not int_clock;
                var := 0;
            else
                var := var+1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Please sort out your code indentation so its easier for us to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my thoughts:

- Your clock divider is going to take some clock that transitions every say 8ns, to one that transitions far less often.
- What happens if `heartin = 1` on a `rising_edge` of `clk_in`, but not a `rising_edge` of `wire`?
- It's not clear to me why you're dividing the clock in the first place. At what pace does your heartbeat occur?

It's not clear to me why your code can't look similar to what it currently does, but skipping the clkdivider all together, and just run your counter logic through the faster clock.